# grouping css styles for future use

Tags: css, styles

I am just wandering if there is any way in css file to created something like groups or objects of css styles that can be applied to particular class/element/id later.
For example I want to have few different background styling (bg1, bg2, bg3) and border styling (brd1, ,brd2, brd3) and I want an element .class to have bg2 and bdr1 styles. I just dont want to duplicate css styles and trying to avoid giving too many classes to an element.
Hope it make sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a CSS preprocessor.
Look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

You will be able to use mixins (ie functions) and variables to developp your CSS stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks Finrod, I will check it

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. `:-)`